# I lost the CSS code of my important website, why?

Tags: data-recovery, power, css

Very weird, I had opened Notepad++ and working on my CSS codes for my website, suddenly my little niece unplugged the computer. When I re-started the computer and opened again the same CSS file in Notepad++, all I am seeing is "NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL". There is no code, all is lost.

I opened the same CSS file in other editors and it's all empty, no code.

Is there a way to fix it, because it was my hard work. And what can be the cause?

Comment: Congratulations! You have just learned to Backup Your Work!

Comment: don't feel bad, none of us backed up before we lost something important :(

Comment: Time to learn SubVersion or git?

Answer (score 3):

If the power was lost while you were writing to the disk, it may well have only partially written the file - destroying the contents. I hope you have a backup, unfortunately. As it's a website, has it ever been online? You might strike lucky searching your browser's cache. (My FF cache is in C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles[Profile String].default\Cache).

You're seeing the fancy [NULL] codes because np++ tries to show unprintable characters.

(and for what it's worth, I totally feel your pain. My little sister once accidentally wiped an entire OS, back in the day we booted from floppies :()

Answer (score 1):

most likely something went bad when saving, and its messed up. I'd prolly give recurva or some other file recovery software a shot, and hope for the best. Failing which... in future, you might want to consider using dropbox - it has some version control, and would backup your work as you save it